# Writing an IIF query in Access

Tags: ms-access

I'm attempting to create an Access db to log company domain names, hosting companies, usernames / passwords etc.

I want to create a field with a hyperlink in it which says

`Iif [software] == 'wordpress' , link=url+'wpadmin', else link=url+'admin'`

I cannot see how to make the fields query it and add a button to click which automatically directs the user to the correct admin site.

Can anyone help please? If this php and sql i'd be fine!

Answer (score 2):

In Access, it would be something like this:

```
link = url & IIf([software] = "wordpress", "wpadmin", "admin")
```